# R package help in github gh-pages

Tags: r, github, github-pages, roxygen2, r-package

Given an R package with a git repo on github, I'm looking for an optimal way to build a github hosted (gh-pages) site from the function documentation within the package (in the form roxygen2 comments). It'd be great to be able to include vignettes as well. Can anyone offer some pointers as to how to get started?

Comment: You probably want [pkgdown](https://github.com/hadley/pkgdown) which appears to be the last in series of packages evolving towards this.  And these days you can also publish from `docs/` in the master branch.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally got around to trying [pkgdown](https://github.com/hadley/pkgdown). It's still something of a work in progress, but very usable even at this stage. It does what I want.